# Don't shorten column headings in AgGrid

Tags: javascript, html, ag-grid

How do I go about telling AgGrid to not shorten my column headings? by default I want to be able to see the full column headings when the grid loads and to not have to resize them.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [minWidth](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-width-minWidth) to specify a minimum width for each column. You can also set [suppressSizeToFit](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#reference-columns-sizeColumnsToFit) to true to stop AgGrid from automatically resizing columns when you call [api.sizeColumnsToFit(params)](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-sizing/#reference-columns-sizeColumnsToFit).

##### Example:

```js
// for specific column
const columnDefs = [
  { field: 'athlete', width: 150, suppressSizeToFit: true },
  { field: 'age', width: 50, minWidth: 50 },
  { colId: 'country', field: 'country', minWidth: 300 },
  { field: 'year', width: 90 },
];

// for all columns
const defaultColDef = {
  suppressSizeToFit: true
}
```